# In a vagrant/ansible set up, who is responsible for starting servers (nodejs, rails)

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, ansible

Our infrastructure is getting pretty complex with many moving pieces so I'm setting up Vagrant with Ansible to spin up development environments.

My question is who (Vagrant or Ansible or another tool) should be responsible for starting various such as

- rails s (for starting rails server)
- nginx
- nodejs (for seperate API)

Comment: What do you mean by "who"?

Comment: Vagrant or Ansible or another tool

Comment: Did you read up on the difference between Vagrant and Ansible?  The answer to your question ought to be clear from the definitions of what these tools do.

Comment: Did I ever? I already set up our full dev environment working on it. But provisioner (ansible) installs things, Vagrant sets up the VM, I couldn't find details on who's responsible for "starting" these things. I think it's ansible but its definitions more on the side of installing things and not executing things

Comment: Take a look at e.g. http://docs.ansible.com/service_module.html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is Ansible (or another tool).

Vagrant has capabilities to run scripts and start services.  Once you add a configuration management tool, **it should do exactly that**. That's part of its job: starting and managing services.

You want the same application configuration regardless of the machine you're spinning up (ESXi, Amazon EC2, Vagrant, whatever), and the best way to do that is outside of Vagrant.

Comment: If so, how can I interface through 'vagrant' cmd line to trigger something like 'vagrant restart_services' or something like that which can stop and restart process?

Comment: @TolgaE you don't. These kind of tasks are better suited for Ansible or other management tools. Vagrant is intended to manage VMs. It can do a bit more by the nature that it's Ruby, but that's not its primary purpose.